# re .mar files000

Tags: tor-browser-bundle

Would it be possible for the developers to put new versions into .rar or 7zip?
I cannot get the .mar files to open. It seems like they will only work with the newer versions of MS office. I even tried opening in firefox and it does not work.

Thanks
Betty

Answer (score 1):

[`.mar` file are a *M*ozilla *AR*chive](https://wiki.mozilla.org/Software_Update:MAR).

They are that format that is specific to Mozilla because it is how Mozilla applies updates.

Since they are distributed primarily to be applied as updates to Tor Browser it would not make sense (or really be feasible) to put them into another file format.